# How to copy file from HDFS to the local file system of the cluster nodes, in EMR cluster, using java api,

Tags: java, apache-spark, hdfs, emr

In EMR cluster, using java api, how to copy file from HDFS to the local file system of the cluster nodes?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the new Java 7 way of doing it?

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...)

e.g.

```
private static void copyFileUsingJava7Files(File source, File dest) throws IOException {
    Files.copy(source.toPath(), dest.toPath());
}
```

(From https://www.journaldev.com/861/java-copy-file)

The older way of doing it (java.io.File etc) speaks URIs, so that might be a viable alternative.